Unity 3D. My character is shaking on the surface
I use MVC in my Unity 3D project. I have CollisionPoller to determine contacts and movement. If I use my MoveController and CollisionPoller my character is shaking Y axis every frame per +/- 0.01.
If I use "Is kinematic" it's works, but my character pass through slopes. I can decrease my capsule collider height, but it doesn't work on slopes (my character is shaking again).
public class CollisionPoller
{
    private readonly PlayerView _playerView;
    private const int MaxBounces = 5;
    private const float Threshold = 0.015f;
    private const float MaxSlopeAngle = 45f;
    private Bounds _bounds;

    public CollisionPoller(PlayerView playerView)
    {
        _playerView = playerView;
        _bounds = _playerView.Collider.bounds;
        _bounds.Expand(-2 * Threshold);
    }

    public Vector3 CollideAndSlide(Vector3 velocity, Vector3 position, int depth, bool gravityPass, Vector3 velocityInit)
    {
        if(depth >= MaxBounces)
            return Vector3.zero;
        
        var distance = velocity.magnitude + Threshold;
        if (!Physics.SphereCast(position, _bounds.extents.x, velocity.normalized, out var hit, distance))
            return velocity;
        var snapToSurface = velocity.normalized * (hit.distance - Threshold);
        var leftOver = velocity - snapToSurface;
        var angle = Vector3.Angle(Vector3.up, hit.normal);
            
        if(snapToSurface.magnitude <= Threshold)    
            snapToSurface = Vector3.zero;

        if (angle <= MaxSlopeAngle)     
        {
            if(gravityPass)
                return snapToSurface;
            leftOver = ProjectAndScale(leftOver, hit.normal);
        }
        else
        {
            var scale = 1 - Vector3.Dot(new Vector3(hit.normal.x, 0, hit.normal.z).normalized,
                -new Vector3(velocityInit.x, 0, velocityInit.z).normalized);
            var isGrounded = Physics.Raycast(_playerView.Transform.position, Vector3.down, _bounds.extents.y + 0.1f); 
            if (isGrounded && !gravityPass)
            {
                leftOver = ProjectAndScale(new Vector3(leftOver.x, 0, leftOver.z), 
                    new Vector3(hit.normal.x, 0, hit.normal.z)).normalized;
                leftOver *= scale;
            }
            else
            {
                leftOver = ProjectAndScale(leftOver, hit.normal) * scale;
            }
        }       
        return snapToSurface + CollideAndSlide(leftOver, position + snapToSurface, depth + 1, gravityPass, velocityInit);
    }

    private static Vector3 ProjectAndScale(Vector3 vector, Vector3 normal)
    {
        var magnitude = vector.magnitude;
        vector = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(vector, normal).normalized;
        vector *= magnitude;
        return vector;
    }
}

public class MoveController : BaseController
{
    private readonly PlayerView _playerView;
    private readonly GameModel _gameModel;
    private readonly CollisionPoller _collisionPoller;
            
    public MoveController(PlayerView playerView, GameModel gameModel, CollisionPoller collisionPoller)
    {
        _playerView = playerView;
        _gameModel = gameModel;                         
        _collisionPoller = collisionPoller;
    }

    public void FixedUpdate()
    {
        var horizontalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        var verticalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        
        var direction = new Vector3(horizontalInput, 0, verticalInput).normalized;
        var moveDirection = _collisionPoller.CollideAndSlide(direction, _playerView.Transform.position, 0, false, direction);
        moveDirection += _collisionPoller.CollideAndSlide(Vector3.down, _playerView.Transform.position + moveDirection, 0, true, Vector3.down);
        _playerView.Rigidbody.MovePosition(_playerView.Rigidbody.position + moveDirection * (_gameModel.CurrentPlayer.WalkSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime));    
    }
}


I don’t fully understand your code sample. But I suspect you’re snapping to the surface, but the collider overlaps the surface’s collider ever so slightly.
And that collision causes the object to want to shoot away from each other since they are colliding. So it starts moving away again.
But then as it moves away, it’s within your snapping distance so it stays down again. And this repeats, which causes the jitter.
When you snap, you probably want to turn off physics for the object (which you noticed with iskinematic), and then when it’s time to stop snapping you turn physics back on once the object is far enough away to not cause any weird collisions.
